# Entity Framework Core - Sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to sort my data set like this:

```
public async Task<ICollection<Article>> SortArticles(string sortOrder)
{
    IQueryable<Article> articles = GetAll();
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc": 
            articles.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name).AsQueryable();
        break;
        case "date":
            articles = articles.OrderBy(s => s.DateCreated).AsQueryable();
        case "date_desc":
            articles = articles.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated).AsQueryable();
        break;
        default:
             articles.OrderBy(s => s.Name).AsQueryable();
        break;
    }
    var result = await articles.ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

However, my result is always the ordered same way.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code appears inconsistent, though I cannot say for certain if it is the cause. Your second case statement is missing its "break;", and your first and last statements are missing their assignments.

Comment: i have edited to include the break

Comment: Still missing `break` for `case "date":`. And missing `articles = ` in some cases.

Comment: my edit needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @Daniaal Please do not edit questions to modify code. We don't know whether the OP's code actually has that `break;` or not.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ah ok sorry ill keep in mind for next time.

Comment: @user3569564 can you accept the answer which has helped u

Answer (score 1):

Added the missing break and you are also missing the assignment of the sort.

```
public async Task<ICollection<Article>> SortArticles(string sortOrder)
{
    IQueryable<Article> articles = GetAll();
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc": 
            articles = articles.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name).AsQueryable();           
        break;
        case "date":
            articles = articles.OrderBy(s => s.DateCreated).AsQueryable();
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            articles = articles.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated).AsQueryable();
            break;
        default:
             articles = articles.OrderBy(s => s.Name).AsQueryable();
            break;
    }
    var result = await articles.ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, specially when it's not clear what you changed

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method for the dynamic sorting of the result set. You need to use **property** parameters as sorting column in database.

You can modify the

```
this IEnumerable<<TT>> source
```

to

```
this IQueryable<<TT>> source
```

if required or causing an error.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, bool isDescending, string property)
    {
        if (isDescending)
        {
            return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetReflectedPropertyValue(property));
        }
        else
        {
            return source.OrderBy(x => x.GetReflectedPropertyValue(property));
        }
    }

    private static object GetReflectedPropertyValue(this object subject, string property)
    {
        return subject.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(subject, null);
    }
```